# Percentage increase or decrease between two values

Tags: php

How do I calculate the percentage of increase or decrease of two numbers in PHP?

For example: (increase)100, (decrease)1 = -99%
             (increase)1, (decrease)100 = +99%

Comment: Provide more understandable description

Answer (score 2):

Before anything else you need to have a solid understanding of the meaning of percentages and how they are computed.

The meaning of *"`x` is `15%` of `y`"* is:

```
x = (15 * y) / 100
```

The arithmetic operations with percentages are similar. If `a` increases with `12%` (of its current value) then:

```
a = a + (12 * a) / 10
```

Which is the same as:

```
a = 112 * a / 100
```

Subtracting `9%` (of its current value) from `b` is:

```
b = b - (9 * b) / 100
```

or

```
b = b * 91 / 100
```

which actually is `91%` of the value of `b` (`100% - 9%` of `b`).

---

Turn the above `a`, `b`, `x`, `y` into PHP variables (by placing `$` in front of them), terminate the statements with semicolons (`;`) and you get valid PHP code that performs percentage operations.

PHP doesn't provide any particular function that helps working with percentages. As you can see above, there is no need for them.

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents ;)

**Using PHP**

```
function pctDiff($x1, $x2) {
    $diff = ($x2 - $x1) / $x1;
    return round($diff * 100, 2);
}
```

Usage:

```
$oldValue = 1000;
$newValue = 203.5;
$diff = pctDiff($oldValue, $newValue);
echo pctDiff($oldValue, $newValue) . '%'; // -79.65%
```

**Using Swift 3**

```
func pctDiff(x1: CGFloat, x2: CGFloat) -> Double {
    let diff = (x2 - x1) / x1
    return Double(round(100 * (diff * 100)) / 100)
}

let oldValue: CGFloat = 1000
let newValue: CGFloat = 203.5
print("\(pctDiff(x1: oldValue, x2: newValue))%") // -79.65%
```